# dual of the global section of line bundle $\mathscr{O}(1)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, line-bundles

I'm reading about the line bundles on projective spaces and there is something that I couldn't make sense of. Maybe I'm missing some definition so please correct me.

Over $\mathbb{P}_k^1$, I know that $\mathscr{O}(-1)=\mathscr{O}(1)^\vee$, and $\Gamma(\mathbb{P}_k^1,\mathscr{O}(1))$ can be identified with the degree 1 polynomials in $x_0,x_1$, but there is no nonzero global section for $\mathscr{O}(-1)$.

But as definition, $$\Gamma(\mathbb{P}_k^1,\mathscr{O}(-1))=\Gamma(\mathbb{P}_k^1,\mathscr{O}(1))^\vee=Hom_{\Gamma(\mathbb{P}_k^1,\mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}_k^1})}(\Gamma(\mathbb{P}_k^1,\mathscr{O}(1)),\Gamma(\mathbb{P}_k^1,\mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}_k^1})).$$
Here $\Gamma(\mathbb{P}_k^1,\mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}_k^1})\simeq k$, and as $k$-module $\Gamma(\mathbb{P}_k^1,\mathscr{O}(1))\simeq k^2$. Then how could $\Gamma(\mathbb{P}_k^1,\mathscr{O}(-1))$ be zero?

Comment: Your definition of $\Gamma(\Bbb P^1,\mathcal{O}(-1))$ as $\Gamma(\Bbb P^1,\mathcal{O}(1))^\vee$ is not correct. Dualizing does not commute with taking global sections.